# find the nearest node that has one-of data

Tags: netlogo

i have two breeds

```
breed[nodes]
breed [messages]
nodes-own [data]
messages-own [basedata]
```

i have a network with n nodes. each node has a specific data. im selecting a random turtle as sink.in my network data distributed from a turtle(first all turtles are nodes) to sink.each node that is in the way becomes a message.and each message has a memory space too keep those data that pass from that message.messages basedata keep the original data.
i want sink find the nearest node that has for example "D1".

```
to setup
setup1
setup-spatially-clustered-network ;create links
ask links [set color white]
end

to setup1

  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks
create-nodes number-of-nodes
 [
   setxy (random-xcor * 0.95) (random-ycor * 0.95)
   set shape "circle"
   set color green
   set value ["D1" "D2" "D3" "D4" "D5" "D6"]
   set data one-of value
   set label data
   set dontpick false 
   set visit false  
   ]
end

    to test1
    ask one-of turtles
    [
      set color red
      set label "sink"
      set nodenumberdestination who 
    ]
    ask min-one-of turtles with [(data = "D1") or (basedata = "D1")][distance turtle nodenumberdestination]
    [
    ]
    error : NODES breed does not own variable BASEDATA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is when you do

`ask min-one-of turtle with [(data = "D1") or (basedata = "D1")]`

it could refers to either `nodes` and `message`, while each other doesn't share the same variable.

For example: when it runs on nodes, it will return error when checking `[(basedata="D1")]` since it doesn't own `basedata`. Likewise, when it runs on message it will return error when checking `[(data="D1")]` as well. However, since you haven't created any `messages` so it will always returning `error : NODES breed does not own variable BASEDATA`

So, you need to be specific when referring to agentset because any command blocks including variable used will be sensitive to as whose the variables are belong to.

Comment: thank for your response, do you have any suggestion to do this? i mean find the nearest node or message with specific data?

Comment: I didn't really get what do you want to be modeled. But I think you should follow Alan's suggestion. I believe it answers your question

Comment: i have a network with n nodes(at first) and select one of turtles as sink.this sink search for some data and the node that has data start sending its data to sink.each node that is in the way from source to sink becomes a message that has a memory space(each message can keep 3 data item in its memory space).this process repeat for multiple times.at each time one random turtle select as a sink, and request for a data(maybe nearest turtle that has requested  data is a node, or maybe its a message (so it has data in its memory space). i dont if i can explain it or not :D

Comment: okay, I don't know if it works, because i haven't tested it,change the let _choice inside the ask sink by alan with `let _choice min-one-of turtles with [ (breed="nodes" and data="D1") or (breed="messages" and basedata="D1")] [distance myself]`

Answer (score 3):

There is a conflict between your stated goals in your question and your code, which suggests you have not finished thinking through what you are doing.  (The code you posted is also incomplete; for example, it does not include your `globals` declaration nor `setup-messages`.)  So first a question: did you really mean to use `turtles` instead of `nodes` in `test1`?  If yes, that means you allow a `message` to become your sink.  So I'll assume no, as suggested by your actual question.  Introduce a new global `sink` and

```
to test1a
  ask one-of nodes [ ;move this to setup!
    set sink self
    set label "sink" set color red
  ]
  ask sink [
    let _choice min-one-of (other nodes with [data = "D1"]) [distance myself]
    ask _choice [] ;do something
  ]
end
```

That answers your question as asked.  If you really wanted a choice out of all turtles, as suggested by your posted code, you'll have to ask a new question.

Comment: yes,your right,sorry for my mistakes. but my main problem is that i want nearest turtle(nodes or messages) with specific data. and thats because when i repeat my test nodes becomes messages.